# AWS StepFuncton executionArn format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

If I run `StartExecution` specifying the optional parameter `name` (The name of the execution.)

Can I get the `executionArn` as follows?

```
stateMachineArn:name
```

I know that I can get the the `executionArn` in the response of `StartExecution` but I would like to pass the `executionArn` as input to my execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible using the name field.  I have an example below to show how to do it:

StateMachine (name='Helloworld-test'):

```
{
  "Comment": "A Hello World example of the Amazon States Language using a Pass state",
  "StartAt": "HelloWorld",
  "States": {
    "HelloWorld": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Execution name:

```
exsname
```

Execution Input (you can construct this here):

```
{
  "arn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:195788859115:execution:Helloworld-test:exsname"
}
```

Output from Execution:

```
{
  "arn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:195788859115:execution:Helloworld-test:exsname"
}
```

Hope this helps!